# Is it possible to remove all not translation related captions/subtitles from an SRT file?

Tags: subtitles

I want to remove the captions from subtitles in SRT files. I just want the translations in movies not everything they say and all the SRTs I’ve come across don’t have the markers that show a difference so the editor doesn’t help.

Just wondered if I have to do the tedious work or a find a better subtitler?

Answer (score 0):

## No.

### SRT files are simply basic text files with text and placement timings to display that text with a video.

Unfortunately, no. This cannot be done. SRT files are simply text files that contain text and timings related to the display of text with a video. There is no differentiation between the text that is a translation of dialogue or text that is the equivalent of a closed caption.

That said, it seems like the SRT files you have come across are not subtitles (which you want) but rather closed captioning (which you don’t want). Closed captioning is — by design — a form of subtitling that includes all kinds of details about the sounds of a film that are provided for people who are deaf or hard of hearing. Things like descriptions such as “Door Closes” or “Car Honks” and such.

So the best suggestion is to simply find real subtitles for your videos and not closed captioning files.

Comment: The ones I get have both, guess I just gotta keep looking or do the work myself. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by “The ones I get have both…” you mean the videos or the subtitles have both? An MKV can contain multiple subtitle streams and such.

Comment: I have srt's with subtitles and captions from opensubtitle.org

Comment: @Jeremy Better to find another source.